# Flashtool does not convert .swf to .png, says JPEG library not compiled

Tags: macos, homebrew

I've made this sh script to convert a bunch of swf files in a directory to pngs.

`for img in *.swf; do swfrender "$img" -o "$img.png"; done;`

This gives `Error: No JPEG library compiled inrfxswf:`

I've tried variants of this script, and they give the same error.

I am running El Capitan, and I have `libjpeg` and `flashtools` installed via brew.